# finding missing id's in java list

Tags: java, jsp

im trying to make a table that shows wich id can you pick for the object (employee) that you are adding to the database. 
the options will be the last one+1 and all of the "free" id spots that got free by deleting their object.

im trying to create a list of all the missing ids and it dosent work for me. 
i made this with jsp and it just shows all id's on the way to my top id.

```
  int lastId =tableList.get(aAdmin.getAllEmps().size()-1).getId();
    List <Integer> idList=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int counter=0;
    itr= tableList.iterator();
    int i=0;
    while(itr.hasNext()){
    Employee tempEmp=itr.next();
    int id=tempEmp.getId();
    if(id!=i+counter){
    for(int j=0 ; j<id-(i+counter); i++)
    idList.add(i+counter+j);
    counter=counter+(id-(i+counter));
    }
    i++;}
    Iterator<Integer> idItr=idList.iterator();
    while(idItr.hasNext()) {
    Integer tempInt= idItr.next();
    %>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <%=tempInt %><input type="radio" name="id" value="<%=tempInt%>">
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <%}%>
    </table>
    <br>
```

any ideas ?

Comment: You should try to do this with a simple List of Integer in pure java, and start from there

Comment: In general, picking an ID that has been previously used by someone else is setting yourself up for trouble in the future. Unless your company reasonably expects to hire more than two billion people, you do not need to be frugal with integers.

Comment: Never reuse IDs from deleted entities.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do? What is `counter` for, what's your intention for the `idList`?

Comment: @RealSkeptic well im running on the list and comparing the current index to the next employee id in the list. if suddenly the index isnt as same as the id , i probably went right now trough an empty id slot. the counter helps me get how many free slots ive been trough. im also checking if i maybe ran trough 2 empty id slots in the same loop run.

any way it didnt work but that was the idea....

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume we have list of Integers (ids already used) and expect to have a `Set<Integer>` for the ids which are free.

Define a max variable.

Go through the list of existing ids.

If current id from the list is bigger than `max` add all the numbers between `old max` and `new max` and set the `max` to the new value to the Set. If it's smaller than `max` remove it from the Set.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like i found the best solution!

need to debug more things before i check it , but looks like the answer was in sql.
i made table full of all possible id locations and than created a join, got it into a result set and worked with that result set.
the join is -

```
SELECT tempTable.ID, Employees.ID FROM Employees RIGHT JOIN tempTable on Employees.ID=tempTable.ID WHERE (((Employees.ID)Is Null))
```